# Implementação de fila com prioridade usando vetor

Tags: java, array, fila

Estou implementando uma fila com prioridade por meio de um vetor, meu método pra inserção funciona normalmente:

```
public boolean inserir(int n){


if(estaCheia()) {
    return false;
}

if(estaVazia()) {
    fila[nItens++] = n;
    return true;
} else {

    int i; 
    for(i = nItens-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(n > fila[i]){
            fila[i+1] = fila[i];
        } else{
            break;
        }
    }

    fila[i+1] = n;
    nItens++;
    return true;
}

}
```

O único problema é quando vou recuperar o primeiro elemento da fila, fico com uma posição livre no vetor, mas ao tentar inserir surge uma expection ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, acredito que seja porque o espaço livre no vetor é o primeiro. O que devo fazer pra reorganizar o vetor de modo que seja possível inserir nele depois de ter removido o primeiro elemento da fila?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você está fazendo uma fila baseada em vetor, é preciso reorganizar o vetor após uma remoção. Esse é o preço a se pagar pelo uso de uma estrutura estática, mas que pode ser um ótimo preço caso a aplicação trabalhe com poucas remoções.

Você vai precisar de algo assim no seu algoritmo de remoção:

```
for (int i = posicaoDoElementoRemovido; i < tamanhoDaFila-1; i++) {
    fila[i] = fila[i+1];
}
```

Ou seja, cada posição recebe o valor da próxima.

Uma sugestão extra: troque esse seu retorno do tipo `boolean` por um `void`. Se sua estrutura estiver cheia, lance uma exceção.